# How to go back with WebView inside Fragment controlled by NavHostFragment?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-components

Current situation:

- There is only one activity called MainActivity.
- MainActivity maintains the NavHostFragment.
- There is a WebViewFragment which embeded a WebView inside.
- Thera are many other fragment controlled by NavHostFragment.

What troubles me:

I can forward web pages inside WebView, but when I press back to go back inside the WebView, the NavController handle's it, pop the fragment away. 
Since the WebView is inside a fragment not an activity, which means there is not method called `onBackPressed()` to override.

Reference:

- See [NavigationBasicSample@github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationBasicSample)
- See [Getting start with Navigation@android developer home](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you need a way to handle `onBackPressed` on your fragment, right? With `NavigationComponent` you can do it like this, in your `onViewCreated`:

```
 requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
              if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
             } else {
               findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.dest, false)
             }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

add a new fragment and  inside that  place your WebView ,using navigation editor navigate from WebViewFragment  to new fragment ,in the right hand side of navigation editor you can see an option to backstack option to manage .

Answer (score 0):

code lab has example https://codelabs.developers.google.com/handling-gesture-back-navigation#5 you need onBackPressedDispatcher which need to be enabled and disabled.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.](/help/referencing).

Answer (score -1):

you can use mWeb.goBack(); to goBack to the previous page or for returning back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you might have misunderstand what I'm trying to solve.